# Can drag and drop be disabled in the DataTables colReorder extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using DataTables 1.10.12 and colReorder 1.3.2. moving columns using the order method works great, but I want to disable the drag and drop column movement as we are supplying a different interface for that. I do not see an option for that so far; am I missing one? Or is there another way of reordering the columns without enabling colReorder?

I did look at the column-reorder event thinking I could cancel the drags, but I didn't see a way to distinguish the events from drags vs programmatic moves.

Comment: Have you ever solved this problem? I have the same issue and don't know how to implement it.

Comment: @a-x-i No I never did. Given the requirements I realized that I was overriding/working around more of DataTables than I was using so I spent a couple of days and replaced it with plain-old html tables, js & css. In the end it wasn't bad and haven't regretted the decision. No disrespect to DataTables; it's awesome for the right job, this just wasn't it.

Comment: I solved the problem on changing the code of colreorder plugin: removed the code in _fnMouseListener where mousedown and later on mousemove is handled.